# Indexing 7TB of data with elasticsearch. FScrawler stops after sometime

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler

I am using fscrawler to create an index of data above 7TB. The indexing starts fine but then stops when the index size gets to 2.6gb. I believe this is a memory issue, how do I configure the memory?

My machine memory is 40GB and I have assigned 12GB to elasticsearch.

[image]

Comment: please edit your post and replace image with content of your yaml file. This way people will be able to copy-paste text and use it for further search and so on.

Comment: this might help with your issue https://www.slideshare.net/AndrewClegg1/scaling-elasticsearch-for-multiterabyte-analytics

Answer (score 1):

You might have to assign as well enough memory to FSCrawler using [`FS_JAVA_OPTS`](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/jvm-settings.html). Like:

```
FS_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4g -Xms4g" bin/fscrawler
```